# PyTorch CNN: Loss is unchanging

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have tried researching a situation for my unchanging loss, and all the answers I found were specific to the code. I just started learning about CNNs and majority of the CNN is from an example and modified to fit the needs of my dataset. I am trying to classify types of ECGs (normal, atrial fibrillation, other, noisy). When I try to train the CNN the loss remains the same, I think this is because my CNN does not learn and only outputs zeros. So far I have tried changing the learning rate/loss function and have made no difference.

I am doing this on [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fR29ffY9iJW-to7fgsjRVmAKo4jtImP1) so feel free to edit the code, and don't forget to change hardware acceleration under the runtime tab to GPU.

Code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.io import loadmat
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if torch.cuda.is_available():
  device = torch.device("cuda:0")
  print("Running on GPU -", device )
else:
  device = torch.device("cpu")
  print("Running on CPU -", device )


REBUILD_DATA = True # processing data

class ECG_DATA():
  ECG_LENGTH = 3000
  LABEL_SIZE = 485
  DATA = "physionet.org/files/challenge-2017/1.0.0/training/"
  NORMAL = "physionet.org/files/challenge-2017/1.0.0/training/RECORDS-normal" 
  AF = "physionet.org/files/challenge-2017/1.0.0/training/RECORDS-af"
  OTHER = "physionet.org/files/challenge-2017/1.0.0/training/RECORDS-other"
  NOISY = "physionet.org/files/challenge-2017/1.0.0/training/RECORDS-noisy"
  LABELS = {NORMAL: 0, AF: 1, OTHER:2, NOISY: 3}
  trainingData = []
  dataCount = {NORMAL: 0, AF: 0, OTHER: 0, NOISY: 0}

  def make_training_data(self):
    for records in self.LABELS:
      with open(records) as label:
        for ecgFile in tqdm(label):
          ecg = loadmat(self.DATA+ecgFile[:-1]+".mat")["val"][0].tolist()

          if records == self.NOISY:
            #self.zero_padding(ecg)
            for x in range(self.ECG_LENGTH, len(ecg), self.ECG_LENGTH):
              if self.dataCount[records] <= self.LABEL_SIZE and x <= len(ecg):
                self.trainingData.append([np.array(ecg[x-self.ECG_LENGTH:x]), np.eye(len(self.LABELS))[self.LABELS[records]]])
                self.dataCount[records] += 1

          elif self.dataCount[records] <= self.LABEL_SIZE and self.ECG_LENGTH <= len(ecg):
            self.trainingData.append([np.array(ecg[:self.ECG_LENGTH]), np.eye(len(self.LABELS))[self.LABELS[records]]])
            self.dataCount[records] += 1    
    
    print(self.dataCount)
    np.random.shuffle(self.trainingData)
    np.save("training_Data.npy", self.trainingData)
  
  def zero_padding(self, ecg):
    ecg += [0] * (self.ECG_LENGTH-(len(ecg)%self.ECG_LENGTH))
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # just run the init of parent class (nn.Module)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 32, 5) # input is 1 image, 32 output channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(32, 64, 5) # input is 32, bc the first layer output 32. Then we say the output will be 64 channels, 5x5 kernel / window
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(64, 128, 5)

        x = torch.randn(1,3000).view(-1,1,3000)
        self._to_linear = None
        self.convs(x)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self._to_linear, 512) #flattening.
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 4) # 512 in, 2 out bc we're doing 2 classes (dog vs cat).

    def convs(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool1d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), 1) # adjust shape of pooling?
        x = F.max_pool1d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 1) # x = F.max_pool1d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool1d(F.relu(self.conv3(x)), 1)

        if self._to_linear is None:
            self._to_linear = x[0].shape[0]*x[0].shape[1]
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, self._to_linear)  # .view is reshape ... this flattens X before 
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x) # bc this is our output layer. No activation here.
        return F.softmax(x, dim=1)


net = Net().to(device)
print(net)

if REBUILD_DATA:
  ECG = ECG_DATA()
  ECG.make_training_data()

training_data = np.load("training_Data.npy", allow_pickle=True)
print(len(training_data))

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss().to(device)

X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in training_data])
y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in training_data])
 
VAL_PCT = 0.1
val_size = int(len(X)*VAL_PCT)
print(val_size)

train_X = X[:-val_size]
train_y = y[:-val_size]

test_X = X[-val_size:]
test_y = y[-val_size:]
print(len(train_X), len(test_X))

BATCH_SIZE = 100
EPOCHS = 1
plot = []

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE)): # from 0, to the len of x, stepping BATCH_SIZE at a time. [:50] ..for now just to dev
        #print(f"{i}:{i+BATCH_SIZE}")
        batch_X = train_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1,1,3000).to(device)
        batch_y = train_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].to(device)

        net.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(batch_X)
        loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()    # Does the update
    
    plot.append([epoch, float(loss)])
    print(f"\nEpoch: {epoch}. Loss: {loss}")

plot = list(map(list, zip(*plot)))
plt.plot(plot[0], plot[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

At the end of your network there's a softmax layer but in your training you use `MSELoss`. This tells me that your model is outputting probabilities but then you are calculating loss as if it is continuous. Not sure exactly how that is working for you but I would suspect this is a reason for faulty loss.

As mentioned below in the comments, you can use `CrossEntropyLoss` with your softmax layer intact - since your task is about classification.

Comment: since it's about *classification* of ECGs, you can mention in the answer that OP can try `CrossEntropyLoss` instead.

Comment: @jchaykow, I removed the softmax function, the loss does change but buy .001 at the best. What could be the reason, I updated the Colab so you can see the results there. I tried to tune the lr but no luck. Also, I tried CrossEntropyLoss but my training data labels are 1-hot encoded and CrossEntropyLoss doesn't accept that. Thanks, btw

Comment: @AdityaKendre yes `train_y` will have to be transformed such that it is a number corresponding to which class the model is meant to predict. Don't remove the softmax layer if you are using `CrossEntropyLoss`. And also just to make sure, in your example you use `EPOCHS = 1` which means it will only print loss once at the end of the first epoch. Are you running more than 1 epoch? Or are you running this epoch multiple times?

Comment: @jchaykow, after adding ```CrossEntropyLoss```, and readding the ```softmax``` function, the loss went back to not changing. I think this is because my CNN is actually not learning, it is always outputting 0. This is also the case with MSELoss, which leads me to believe that something is wrong with my net, but I can' seem to find what is.

Comment: @AdityaKendre also, in your example you use `EPOCHS = 1` which means it will only print loss once at the end of the first epoch. Are you running more than 1 epoch?

Comment: @jchaykow, they sorry, I am running 3 EPOCHS

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use `softmax` with `CrossEntropyLoss` because CE loss itself has a softmax i.e. it is a combination of softmax and negative log likelihood (`NLLLoss`).